# Want to know about latest release in the windows phone 7 development

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Kindly tell me when will we get the latest release in the windows phone 7 development. because there is no database support in our last release to Compact Edition,So let me know the up coming release of windows phone 7 development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been no public announcements about inclusion of client database support in a future version of the Windows Phone 7 operating system or framework and tools. However, there are a number of options available already, which include [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com), [Windows Phone 7 Database](http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/), Perst[3](http://www.mcobject.com/perst/), [SQLite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151179/SQLite-on-WP7.aspx), and another one who's name I can't remember.

If you want to know what's coming up in the next major release of the operating system and developer tools, you should pay attention to the upcoming [MIX '11 conference](http://visitmix.com/events/) in Las Vegas (April 12-14). You won't find anyone prepared to talk about what to expect until after then.

**UPDATE:** The other product I was thinking of was [NinjaDB Lite/Pro](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/c-9-windows-phone-7.aspx) from Kellerman Software.

Comment: In MIX '11 conference in Las Vegas (April 12-14) Announced the next version of Windows Phone (code named Mango) will ship later this year, Specific to the refreshed Windows Phone Developer Tools that arrive in May, we’ve also added;

A new profiler and emulator for testing
Support for Silverlight AND XNA in the same project
Structured storage that enables access to SQL database
Access to calendar and contacts through apps
And much more